# Heroku CLI error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, heroku, certificate, firewall, heroku-cli

I am behind in my company's firewall. We use a certificate file *.crt provided from our company to access SSL enabled web sites.

So I am getting `unable to get local issuer certificate` error when using `heroku login`.

I am using Windows 10 and Heroku CLI 7.14.1 and tried adding `HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable` and `SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\certificate.crt` as environment variable but no success.

How can I solve that?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli

Add an environment variable as `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` that points to the certificate.

For Windows:
`set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:\path\to\ca_cert.pem` *or .crt*

For Linux:
`export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/ca_cert.pem`

Comment: Worked for my mac too. I placed following in my .zshrc file present in user folder so that I don't need to set this variable every time.  Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get that certificate from? Do we have to get that certificate from Heroku console?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10:

Go to System variable (Windows logo key > type: "environment variables" > click Environment Variables button)

Check/Set Variable SSL_CERT_DIR=YourCetrFolder

[image]

Certificate folder Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ask your organization network team to provide the ca cert or pem file. Once you have the cer or .pem file in your local computer, place it in some directory and set it in environment variable.

For example: I have .pem file placed in this location. 'C:\keys\xxx.pem'.
In environment variable i will add new system variable with below given name and value.

Variable Name: 'NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS'
Variable Value: 'C:\keys\xxx.pem'

Once the above steps are followed, open command prompt (close if you have one already opened) and try to enter 'heroku login' and press any key on your keyboard to take you to browser. It will take you to browser to authenticate your user credentials. If your organization has SSO enabled it will take care of itself if not you have to enter your heroku user credentials to authenticate. Once successfully authenticated, you will get back to command prompt with below messages.

Opening browser to 'https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/cli/browser/XXXXXXXX'
Logging in... done
Logged in as 'your user name appear here'

That's it.